# Three dimensional named ranges for dynamic graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts, named-ranges

I have a table which contains values of 10 variables for every day in a calendar year. See attachment for reference.

[image]

I'm trying to create a line chart with the following options:

1. Select any of the 5 variables via 5 difference dropdown (populated by a static named range - **done**)
2. Select start date (named range that takes in all dates in the table - **done**)
3. Select end date (named range with dates starting from above *start date* - **done**)
4. After doing the above I want the chart to display 5 lines for the selected variables for the time period between and including start and end date. - (**not done/unable to figure out how to implement**)

I'm looking for a non-VBA/macro solution as the end-user is not adept with it to make changes in future.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where have you got stuck?

Comment: @Albin, I was able to get the output using FormulaChop method. I was trying to create a single named range that would create the array of all 5 chosen parameters. Never got it to work. I simply made 5 named range for the 5 parameters and got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They key is to combine the `MATCH()` function and the `OFFSET()` function.

I made a spreadsheet that demonstrates this solution, and I put a link to it below.

The single formula I wrote is an array formula, which looks like this:

`{=OFFSET(Offset_Start, MATCH(Variable_Selector, Variable_Col, 0), MATCH(Start_Date, Date_Row, 0)):
OFFSET(Offset_Start, MATCH(Variable_Selector, Variable_Col, 0), MATCH(End_Date, Date_Row, 0))}`

Here is how it works

- This construction is known as a Dynamic Range, where the formula returns a range which is defined by functions, not absolute addresses. In this case, we are using `OFFSET()` to define the start and end of the range the formula returns. Notice the `:` between the two `OFFSET()` functions.
- `Offset_Start` is in the top-left corner of the data. In your screenshot, this is cell `A2`
- Since the variables an in rows, you use `MATCH()` to find which row matches the variable selected
- Since the dates are in columns, you use `MATCH()` to find which column matches the date (start or end) selected
- Make sure to use `MATCH()` with the third argument as `0`, so it returns the exact match
- `OFFSET()` uses the row (2nd argument) and column (3rd argument) found by the `MATCH()` functions to return the cell which corresponds to the input variable and date.
- This is an array formula which occupies a row which is as long as the data. All the cells to the right of the final found value will be `#N/A`

I used FormulaChop to generate the formula above (Full Disclosure: I wrote FormulaChop). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRgaL.png) is a screenshot of the FormulaChop output. [Here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=73519792519993894091) is a link to the spreadsheet that demonstrates how this works.

Comment: This thing works. I ended up creating a different named range for each of the 5 parameters and used MATCH/OFFSET combo to get it done.

Comment: And your software is really good and interesting to get beginners up their excel level.

Comment: @HymnZ I'm glad this worked for you! Thank you for your kind comments. Feel free to download a trial if you think FormulaChop would help you.